# If loop not working properly

Tags: bash, shell, variables

In my script i execute correctly when first time in the if loop execute after the third time of execution its not working properly .what can i do is any mistake ah...? please fix my issue...?in the script i gave the value for customer name as ABC then again i gave the ABC that time it ececute the if condition correctly,but i gave the third time as ABC its not working properly..!

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " --- Enter the Database name ---"
read databasename


echo " --- enter the table name --- "
read table_name

sqlite3 $databasename.db "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name;"

sqlite3 $databasename.db  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name(cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,cus_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ,cus_domain TEXT UNIQUE, cus_status TEXT NOT NULL,Port INTEGER NOT NULL);"


echo " --- Enter the total number of rows do you want ---"
read cus_count


echo "--- Enter the following details one by one---"

port_num=8080

for((i=1;i<=cus_count;i++))
do


echo "enter the $i customer details"

echo "---Enter the customer name---"
read c_name

customer=$(sqlite3 $databasename.db "select cus_name from $table_name")



if [[ "$port_num" == "$port_num" ]]; then
port_num=$(($port_num + 1))
fi


if [[ $c_name != $customer ]]
then
    echo "---Enter the Status(Active/Inactive)---"
    read c_status



c_domain="$c_name"

else
    echo "---OOPS you entered customer name already available---"
    echo "---Please enter new customer name---"

i=$(($i - 1))

fi

sqlite3 $databasename.db "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $table_name (cus_name,cus_domain,cus_status, Port) VALUES(\"$c_name\",\"${c_domain,,}.com\",\"$c_status\",\"$port_num\") ;" 


done

echo " --- Records from the $table_name ---"

sqlite3 $databasename.db "select * from $table_name;"
```

Comment: i found the issue ..It check the cus_name recent value only so its not working properly.if it checks full of the coulumn value it execute correctly.how i can check the full coulmn in the script..?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to below on "bash script arithmetic operations"

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html

or

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html

Comment: I fix that issue

Comment: i found the issue ..It check the cus_name recent value only so its not working properly.if it checks full of the coulumn value it execute correctly.how i can check the full coulmn in the script..?